# Text for callout button on pin annotation

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation

Is it possible to have text instead of an image on the callout buttons from the map view?

Something like this?

```
let leftCalloutButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
leftCalloutButton.text = "jobs"    // this line doesn't compile
pinView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftCalloutButton
```

I've tried a few implementations of setTitle with no success.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton have its own method to set title:

```
leftCalloutButton.setTitle("myTitle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: I eventually realised I also needed a frame, so leftCalloutButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);